# ToolTip dynamically resizing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

```
function OnClientBeforeShow(sender, args) {      
    setTimeout(function () {         
       var active = Telerik.Web.UI.RadToolTip.getCurrent();         
       var browserWidth = $telerik.$(window).width();         
       var browserHeight = $telerik.$(window).height();        
       var width = (Math.ceil(browserWidth * 50 / 100));         
       active.set_width(width);         
       active.get_popupElement().style.width = width + "px";     
   }, 0); 
}
```

I have used this above mentioned script for Telerik RadToolTipManager control in "OnClientBeforeShow" event, it working fine for 1366x768 resolution but if i change the resolution, it is breaking. I need to have dynamic tooltip which will resize according to data it is populated. And please suggest how to adjust font size of text in a tooltip.